# Error in running SWT by eclipse in windows

Tags: path, swt

I am running SWT app(HelloWorld) but it gives me this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
at swt3.demo.main(demo.java:9)
I appreciate if you could please help me?

Comment: You would actually need to show us code first.

Comment: Your code contains compilation errors, you need to resolve those before you can run it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I run it on Ubuntu successfully. But I can not run Maven on that. My Ubuntu is 32, Eclipse is 8 .  I received the following error,
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'ftklipse'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of i